# How get instance in a method clean from some forms

Tags: python, django, django-forms

How can I get the Article instance in my model form's `clean` method? I tried too access `self.instance` but it is `None`. How do I get the previous field values?

model

```
class Article(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=25)
```

forms

```
class ArticleForm(forms.ModelForm)

    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = '__all__'

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        get_instance = self.instance
        print(get_instance) and I get None
```

views

```
def test(request)
    form = ArticleForm({'name':'test', 'value':'test'})
    if form.is_valid():
        print(1)
    else:
        print(form.errors)
```

Answer (score 3):

You get `None` because you didn't instantiate the form with an instance.

```
form = ArticleForm({'name':'test', 'value':'test'})
```

If you instantiate the form with an instance, then you can access it with `self.instance` in the `clean` method.

```
article = Article.objects.get(pk=1)
form = ArticleForm({'name':'test', 'value':'test'}, instance=article)
```

However, note that cleaning the form alters the model instance. If you want the original values, you should refetch the instance from the database, e.g. original_instance = Art

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super().clean()
    if self.instance is not None and self.instance.pk is not None:
        original_instance = Article.objects.get(pk=self.instance.pk)
    else:
        original_instance = None
    ...
```

If you only want to know *which* fields changed, and don't care about their original values, it would be simpler to use the [`changed_data`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.changed_data) attribute.